# Delete ReSharper keymap from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

is there a way to remove ReSharper keyboard layout from Visual Studio 2022?
I had installed ReSharper but I'm not fine and I uninstalled it (formatted my PC). Now, after I reinstalled Visual Studio there is a ReSharper's Keyboard layout that I want to delete.

Thanks for the help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

> When you change a previously selected scheme, the key bindings set by the previous scheme are not canceled out. To remove old key bindings and/or restore Visual Studio key bindings overridden by the IntelliJ IDEA scheme, open Visual Studio options (Tools | Options), go to Environment | Keyboard and click Reset.

[source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)